# during the week(s) vs on the weekend(s)

Tags: grammatical-number

> During *the week*, Nate Brakeley works as a data analyst. But on *the weekends*, he competes with Rugby United New York, the city’s first professional major league rugby franchise, now in its fourth season.

(Source: [New York Times article: How a Professional Rugby Player Spends Sundays](https://www.nytimes.com/2021/07/02/nyregion/rugby-united-new-york.html))

This is the first paragraph of the article. Here, *the week* and *the weekends* refer to weekdays and weekends in general, respectively. Note that *the week* is singular while *the weekends* is plural. And I agree with these choices of singular/plural forms.

Although I could possibly use singular *the weekend* instead of plural *the weekends*, I wouldn't use plural *the weeks* instead of singular *the week*. So I'd like to know two things:

a. Do you agree with me on the choice of singular/plural forms?

b. If so, how would you explain that you can allow *the weekends* to mean "weekends" in general but not *the weeks* to mean "weeks" in general?

Comment: Are you aware of the Old English habit of using of *-s* (originally *-es* like the genitive singular) to form adverbs from singular nouns, leaving us today with things like *He works days/nights* or *This is a workingman's jazz club with music and food served weekdays at noon*? These tend to be reanalysed as plural nouns today rather than adverbs but they're still used adverbially without strictly needing a preposition.

Comment: @tchrist How interesting. No I know nothing about Old English. But I don't know why you need to summon no less than Old English to address the issue at hand. 1. Here, we need prepositions such as _during_ and _on_. 2. _the week_ is not taking the plural form. So I don't know how the Old English bit is helping.

Comment: Because you don't really need the prepositions at all to say that someone works weekdays, and that's a holdover from a long time ago. Which is apparently what you meant by "during the week".

Comment: @tchrist I know nothing about Old English, but I don't understand your explanation that Old English uses -s "to form adverbs from singular nouns". In an Old English counterpart of _He works days_, for example, I think he works not just for a single day but for a plurality of days. If so, the -s in _days_ is not some weird device "to form adverbs from singular nouns" but is just indicating the _days_ is plural. Moreover, in Present-day English, I think _days_ is not an adverb but a noun acting as an adjunct (or adverbial). Is there any reason to treat it as an adverb in Old English?

Comment: @tchrist Unless there is a duplicate, I'd say that you're getting far more answer-avoidancy than I've ever been.

Comment: I want my parallelism back: during the week and on the weekend. For crazy deadlines, dailies get a pass for the occasional typo. Doesn't make every word a model for the times.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Are you sure 'parallelism' is required in cases like this?

Answer (score 2):

> - Our lives are divided into hours, days, **weeks**, months, and years.
> - There are **52 weeks** in a year.

Here the plural forms refer to facts that are indisputable and immutable.

In the NYT article, the journalist writes

> **During the week**, Nate Brakeley works as a data analyst.

This is about a rugby player's *routine*, and the singular *week* **specifically** refers to the *[working week](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/working-week)* (BrEng) / *[workweek](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/workweek)* (AmEng) and there is strong evidence that suggests [the singular form usually has the upperhand](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=during%20the%20week%2C%20during%20the%20weeks&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20weeks%3B%2Cc0) when it follows the preposition *during*.

> **During the morning** / afternoon / night
> [**During the day**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=during%20the%20week%2Cduring%20the%20weeks%2C%20during%20the%20day%2C%20during%20the%20days&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20week%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20weeks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20day%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20days%3B%2Cc0) / week / month of May / year
> **During spring** / summer / fall / winter

Merriam-webster defines *during*

> 1: throughout the duration of *//swims every day during the summer*

Cambridge's definition is

> from the beginning to the end of a particular period. *They work during the night and sleep by day.*

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/during) offers these examples

- *The mill, which was open to the public **during the week**, has had its visiting hours slashed.*
- *Walking through the city **during the morning rush hour** can be a bit of a battle.*

The plural [“during the springs”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=during%20the%20spring%2Cduring%20the%20springs&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20spring%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduring%20the%20springs%3B%2Cc0) would not be ungrammatical but it tends to be highly unusual.

With the prepositions “on", "in" and "at" the plural form is more  idiomatic.

> **In the mornings** / afternoons / evenings
>
> **On Mondays**, Tuesdays etc.
>
> **At the** weekends (BrEng)
>
> **On the** weekends (AmEng)
> [See Ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20the%20weekends%2Cat%20the%20weekend%2C%20on%20the%20weekend%2Con%20the%20weekends&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cat%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cat%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cat%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cat%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bat%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAt%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20weekend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Con%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bon%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BOn%20the%20weekends%3B%2Cc0)
>
> **In the** 1980s

With the exception of the seasons, which normally remains singular

> **In spring** / summer / fall / winter

[According to Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20the%20weeks%20%2A&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cin%20the%20weeks%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20ahead%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20following%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20leading%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20immediately%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20preceding%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cin%20the%20weeks%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20before%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20ahead%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20following%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20after%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20leading%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20immediately%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bin%20the%20weeks%20preceding%3B%2Cc0) the phrases "in the weeks before" and "in the weeks leading to” are the most common but neither can replace "during the week” as the prepositions *before* and *to* are followed by a noun. By doing so the image the journalist seeks to evoke, one of the typical professional working in New York, is spoiled.

> In the weeks before training, Nate Brakeley works as a data analyst…
> In the weeks leading to the championship,…

Comment: Not sure about "in" with plural. I think it might be more common with the singular: I would rather say _[**in the morning**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+morning%2C+in+the+mornings&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20morning%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20mornings%3B%2Cc0) than _**in the morning**_ .

Comment: @fev What I mean to say that the plural form "in the mornings" is more common, compared to "during the mornings”, not in the sense of the most common.

Comment: Oh, I see. Yes, that is definitely true.

Comment: Can you use _on the weeks_ instead of _during the week_ to mean "weekdays" in general? I mean does this work for you? _**On the weeks**, Nate Brakeley works as a data analyst. But on the weekends, he competes with Rugby United New York, the city’s first professional major league rugby franchise, now in its fourth season._ Also, can you think of some other examples where _on the weeks_ can mean "weekdays" in general?

Comment: @listeneva A week is seven days, so "**In the weeks leading up to July**,  *Michael worked hard*" This would also include the weekends.

Comment: Without the addition of "weekend(s)" in the original excerpt,  readers might interpret that Nate Brakeley "during the week" as him working 6 or 7 days a week. It is possible, but usually our experience tell us that people don't normally work 7 days a week.

Comment: @listeneva In British English and I think in American English, it's **in the week(s)**. The phrase  refers to "weekdays" if you want to emphasise that something happens *7 days a week*, we tend to say "every day".

Comment: In the NYT article, you can't substitute _in the weeks_ for _during the week_, so I don't know why you are even mentioning it. The reason I asked about _on the weeks_ being used instead of _during the week_ in the original text was because you had claimed that the preposition _during_ was the culprit in disallowing the plural form in *_during the weeks_.

Comment: @listeneva you specifically asked if "on the weeks" could mean *"weekdays in general"*. The simple answer is no. Instead you can say ***Five days a week*** *Brakeley works as a data analyst. But **on the weekends** he competes* ...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I wanted to make sure that we're on the same page. Since _on the weeks_ doesn't work, which you have admitted it doesn't, your answer focusing on the kinds of prepositions (during vs in, at, on) doesn't seem to hold water.

Comment: @listeneva please find examples of *on the weeks*, I have said that in English the most usual preposition is *in*. I have given evidence that the preposition "during" usually requires the singular form. I have also explained in the comments that if someone wants to use the the plural form of *weeks* a different construction will be necessary, such as ***In the weeks [of June and July]** OR **In the weeks [leading to the qualifications]** *Brakeley plays rugby*.

Comment: The problem with _in the weeks_ is, as you have made abundantly clear through your own examples, _the weeks_ in _in the weeks_ cannot denote "weeks in general". It can only denote a specific period of time using the units of "weeks" (meaning seven days). So even _in the weeks_ cannot substitute "during the week" in the original text.

Answer (score 0):

> **During the week**, Nate Brakeley works as a data analyst. But **on the weekends**, he competes with Rugby United New York, the city’s first professional major league rugby franchise, now in its fourth season.

There would be greater [parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/parallelism_(grammar)) in using *on the weekend*, which also works and would be prefered by some English teachers. Using countable *weekends* makes the imagery a little more vivid, bringing a series of separate rugby games to mind instead of a single generic match that needs to be mentally carried forward to fill out however long RUNY's season lasts. Since this writer is presumably trying to write as vividly as possible and to make Mr Brakeley's weekday work seem especially boring to [create greater contrast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/antithesis) and interest in the article's main topic, you're probably right that the nonparallelism serves those purposes best.

As far as why *during the weeks* seems wrong, it's because native speakers tend to use that construction [for specific sets of weeks](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=during+the+weeks+%2A&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3): *during the weeks of the off season*, *during the weeks immediately after his birth*, *during the weeks and months that followed*, &c. It's far, far less common to discuss specific sets of weekends in this way and so it's much, much less necessary to cleanly distinguish specific vs. general weekends grammatically.

Even here, though, some speakers would consider that the grammar only works because you've already set it up: the countable *weekends* are the specific weekends corresponding with the workweeks just introduced in general terms. It works (less well) in reverse, too: *On the weekend, Nate Brakeley is just another hooker and prop on a wannabe Yank rugby team. But during the weeks he is an up-and-coming data analyst for one of Wall Street's premier firms, looking for potential profit in markets as diverse as Kentucky soybean futures and Sichuan microchip fabrication.*